# Find Byte sequence in a very large file using Python

Tags: python, regex, linux, grep

I want to find the following byte sequence in a very large file (File size is greater than 2 GB) and print 100 bytes right after this byte sequence.

```
0x77 0x??{6-8} 0x78 0x07 0x??{18} 0x87 0x0d 0x00{2}
```

Update: {6-8} denotes a quantifier.

This is similar to a byte signature. Usually, I would use Yara to search for such byte signatures in a file. Apparently, Yara is not processing very large files properly.

Here, ?? represents a wild card character, so it can match any byte.

The following grep command also does not help in this case because my search pattern includes wild cards.

```
grep -obUaP "<\x-hex pattern>" <file>
```

Maybe I need to modify and use some type of regular expression?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the example above exactly what the strings look like (with hex values in place of the wildcards)?

Comment: Does `{6-8}` denote a quantifier?

Comment: What exactly is the pattern you passed to `grep`? It can certainly handle various wildcard expressions, but we can't guess how you tried to pass them in (other than "apparently not correctly").

Comment: I have updated the question. {6-8} denotes a quantifier.

Comment: Is that quantifier applied to the entire left byte? I.e. `0x00{2}` means `0x00 0x00`? Are those spaces there for readability or they exist as literal characters?

Answer (score 0):

If your shell is Bash (or another shell which supports `$'...'` "C-style" strings) and your `grep` is GNU `grep` (as it apparently is), and if I am able to correctly guess what your ad-hoc representation of the search pattern is supposed to represent, try

```
grep -obUaP $'\x77.{6,8}\x78\x07.{18}\x87\x0d\x00{2}\K.{100}' file
```

where `.` matches any byte, `{m,n}` says to repeat the immediately preceding pattern at least `m` and at most `n` times, a single `{n}` repeats something exactly `n` times, and the `\xab` sequences represent a single byte in hex notation. The `K` says to match the whole expression, but only print the part after `\K` (obviously take this out if you actually want to print the signature part, too).

**However,** because you have both `\x00` and `\x0d` in your pattern, I don't think this will work. If your pattern had only either, you could use either `-z` (read a "line" until the next zero byte) or go with the default line-oriented input. If your "anything" sequences could never contain zero bytes, you could temporarily replace zero bytes with (say) `\xfe` and vice versa:

```
tr `\376\000' '\000\376' <file | grep ...
```

where obviously you'd add `-z` to the `grep` options, and change the pattern to look for `\xfe` where your original pattern had zeros. (I *think* GNU `grep` still uses `\xff` for its own nefarious internal purposes, though I'm not in a place where I can verify this.)

**Or** you could break down and do this in Python after all. Read a buffer (say, 8192 bytes) at a time, look for the pattern in that byte string, then keep the last 100-odd bytes from the previous read and append the next buffer to the kept sequence, then loop until eof.